# A same code worked on localhost but didnt work on server

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to insert some data into database. Before inserting into database, it will check whether the record is exist or not by using `mysqli_num_rows`. Below is my part of code

```
$agentSQL = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE agent_no = "'.$agentNo.'" and id = "'.$agentMemberID.'"';

if (!$agentChk = mysqli_query($dbCon, $agentSQL)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Error: %s\n', mysqli_error($dbCon));</script>";
    exit();
}

$agentChkrow = mysqli_num_rows($agentChk);

if ($agentChkrow != 0) {
  //insert data
} else {
  //record exist
}
```

It has several types of agent, eg. USA agent, Fr agent, Kr agent. So that it will be look like:

```
if($_POST['type'] == "USA agent"){
  //above code
} else if ($_POST['type'] == "Fr agent"){
  //above code
} else if ($_POST['type'] == "Kr agent"){
  //above code
} else {
  //blablabla
}
```

And the current problem is the entire code is worked on localhost, and only the part of `Fr agent` didn't work. When I get the error message from the script and the error is

`MySQL server has gone away`

also it will get `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in` error without using `or die(mysqli_error($dbCon)`

I've searched some of solution by this error message. But it seems not relevant to `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout` and `max allowed packet` since only a part of code didn't work and the remaining code work normally. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your code is working like you want it? You have `if ($agentChkrow != 0) {
  //insert data
} else {
  //record exist
}`
You are doing it wrong, this `if($agentChkrow != 0)`, in this case, means if not zero, or is this case if found something, but you should use `if($agentChkrow > 0)`.

And by your edit, it seems you are missing some database connection.

Comment: Do you have a valid connection object? It looks like (boolean given) that your connection object is false.

Comment: @lmarcelocc yeah, I think. It is working on localhost. But when I upload the files onto server it cause the above error.

Comment: Your localhost database log in credentials might be different from the databse in your other sever.

Comment: In this case, your else is `if($agentChkrow == 0) { // Here record don't exist in DB }`

also checked you login details from your server, the could be diferent from the one you use locally.

Comment: @derdida Yeah. The part of code in `usa agent` and `kr agent` worked normally, but it cause the above error in `fr agent` cases ( on server)

Comment: Also, where and how do you get the  `$agentNo` and `$agentMemberID` values?

Comment: @lmarcelocc from `$_POST['agentNo']` and `$_POST['agentMemberID']`

Comment: And they exist in this case? Are they NOT EMPTY?

Comment: @lmarcelocc yes, they are not empty. I checked by using `echo $agentNo` and `echo $agentMemberID`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71757/discussion-between-lmarcelocc-and-user3571945).